# Ansible Loop Register

Tags: docker, ansible

I have an ansible playbook to create new users and create a docker for each user. The information of the users is gathered from a yaml file there are more that 200 records. The yaml file consists of username and password. To create docker container I have to give PUID and PGID of the user to the docker run command. See below for example command

```
docker run --restart=always -it --init -td -p {port from ansible}:8443 -e PUID={PUID from ansible} -e PGID={PGID from Ansible} linuxserver/code-server:latest
```

I want to get PUID and PGID of a user and register it to a variable to use them to create docker container. I tried to use the following command but since it appends the output to a variable dictionary, I am not able to match the username with PUID/PGID.

```
  - name: GET PUID
    shell: id -u "{{ item.username }}"
    loop: "{{ user }}"
    register: puid
  - name: pgid Variable
    debug: msg="{{ pgid.stdout }}"
```

YAML for user

```
user:
  - username: john.doe
    password: password
```

The docker image that  I want to use: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server

Comment: What does "cannot use it for the specific user" mean? What are you trying to do, and what is happening instead? Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Answer (score 1):

For example, get the UID and GID of user *admin* at *test_11*

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 id admin
uid=1001(admin) gid=1001(admin) groups=1001(admin)
```

Use the module [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-module-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility). The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - set_fact:
        admin_uid: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.admin.1 }}"
        admin_gid: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.admin.2 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |
          admin_uid: {{ admin_uid }}
          admin_gid: {{ admin_gid }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    admin_uid: 1001
    admin_gid: 1001
```